# What does a function of infinite variables look like?

Tags: calculus

A function of a single variable is denoted $f(x)$, of two variables if denoted $f(x,y)$

What about infinite variables? How do we denote such thing and do such things exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example: Let $f:\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\to\mathbb R$ be defined by
$$ f((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}) = x_1, $$
where $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ denotes the set of real valued sequences.

You may say that $f$ has *infinitely many* arguments, namely $x_n$, $n\in\mathbb N$. You may also say $f$ has *one* argument, namely the complete sequence $x = (x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.

**A more intuitive example:**

Consider $I:C[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, defined by
$$ I(f) = \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x, $$
where $C[a,b]$ denotes the set of continuous functions on the compact interval $[a,b]$.
Then, $I$ is a function of *one* argument, namely the function $f$, but also a function of (uncountably) infinitely many arguments $f(x)$, $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: Where do you encounter such math? I don't see any application for this nor have I seen functions of sequences.

Comment: It is called the projection onto the first component. Pretty useful in many places. But people usually don't write out it explicitly.

Comment: @DonaldJ.Panda You see these in functional analysis.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an example in which each variable can change the value of the function, try:

$$f(\vec x) = \sum \frac{1}{(n^2 + |x_n|)}$$

That sum converges (by comparison) no matter what the $x_n$ may be.